# Не дает значок "Любознательный"

Tags: дефект, знаки

[image: Значок "Любознательный"]

Почему мне не дает значок "Любознательный"? Как видно на картинке выше, у меня уже 7/5 достигнуто по этому значку, а он не получен. Это ошибка сервиса? Или я что-то не до конца понимаю по системе значков? Вначале думал, что может выдает с запозданием, но прошло уже около трех дней с момента достижения 5/5.

Comment: [Вот почему](http://i.imgur.com/wRb7t7w.png).

Comment: @D-side, почему не ответом? :-)

Comment: @Grundy потому что: возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему не присуждается знак «Любознательный» («Curious»)](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3561/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%9b%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-curious)

Comment: @D-side мне закрыть вопрос, раз такой уже был?

Comment: Можно. Но даже если вы этого не сделаете, [это сделаем мы](http://i.imgur.com/pGcIpG5.png) :)

Comment: проголосовал за закрытие короче